# Creating a excel pivot table with a adomd.cellset

Tags: excel, pivot-table, mdx

Im developing with vba in excel and wanna create some excelsheets to render a pivot table and a chart.

I did it with recordset which was returned from a custom mdx query. I have a example below which returns the data from the cube into a recordset then creates a pivottable and a chart. Working like a charm.

```
Public Sub CreatePivotTableAndChart()
Dim MDXQuery As String

'Declare variables
Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset

On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

'Open Connection
conn.ConnectionString = "Provider=MSOLAP.7;Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=True;Initial Catalog=xxxxxxx;Data Source=xxxxxxxx;MDX Compatibility=1;Safety Options=2;Protocol Format=XML;MDX Missing Member Mode=Error;Packet Size=32767"
conn.Open

'Custom MDX query
MDXQuery = "WITH" & vbCrLf & _
           "MEMBER [Measures].[DateValue] AS [DT_dTime].[Date].MemberValue" & vbCrLf & _
           "SELECT {[Measures].[DT_mTransactions_Count], [Measures].[DateValue]} ON COLUMNS," & vbCrLf & _
           "(Filter([DT_dTime].[Date].[Date].ALLMEMBERS, [Measures].[DT_mTransactions_Count] > 0)) ON ROWS" & vbCrLf & _
           "FROM ( SELECT ( { [DT_dTags_Gender].[ParentTagID].&[4061],[DT_dTags_Gender].[ParentTagID].&[4062] } ) ON COLUMNS" & vbCrLf & _
           "FROM [DT_BizTrackCube])" & vbCrLf & _
           "WHERE ([DT_dTime].[Month].&[2018-01-01T00:00:00], [DT_dTags_MeasureType].[ParentTagID].&[8])"

rs.Open MDXQuery, conn

'Create new pivot cache
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("TestPivotTable")
Set pc = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlExternal)

rs.MoveFirst

'Set recordset
Set pc.Recordset = rs

'Create new pivot table
Set pt = pc.CreatePivotTable(TableDestination:=ws.Range("A1"), TableName:="PivotTable")

'define pivotfields
pt.PivotFields("[Measures].[DateValue]").Orientation = xlRowField
pt.PivotFields("[Measures].[DT_mTransactions_Count]").Orientation = xlDataField

pt.ManualUpdate = False

'Create new pivot chart
Dim objShape As Shape

ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable").PivotSelect "", xlDataAndLabel, True
Set objShape = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(227, xlLine)

With objShape
    .Select
    'Name formatting, position
    .Name = "PivotChart"
    .Left = Range("E1").Left
    .Top = Range("E1").Top
    .Width = 646
    .Height = 300
    'Titles
    .chart.HasTitle = True
    .chart.ChartTitle.Text = "Maand vergelijking"
    .chart.Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
    .chart.Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Characters.Text = "Dagen"
    .chart.Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
    .chart.Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Characters.Text = "Leads"
End With

'Close recordset
rs.Close

'Reset recordset
Set rs = Nothing

'Close connection
conn.Close

'Reset connection
Set conn = Nothing

Done:
Exit Sub      'Exit to avoid error handler

ErrorHandler:
Debug.Print "ErrorHandler"
' Get VB Error Object's information
strTmp = "VB Error # " & Str(Err.Number)
strTmp = strTmp & vbCrLf & "   Generated by " & Err.Source
strTmp = strTmp & vbCrLf & "   Description  " & Err.Description & vbCrLf

Debug.Print strTmp
End Sub
```

The only problem is with this solution I have flattenend result. I wanna use for example a mdx query with cross join so i can use row grouping (dimensions). The result is a multidimensional result. 
I know that the cube returns a cellset but how can i create a pivot table from a cellset? Is that even possible. I found some examples how you can read a cellset and print the result to a flat table but
not one how to create a pivot table from it.

Hope you can help me out. Thanks in advance.